# Outputting an Array in Column Format

Tags: arrays, c

Here's some instructions for my project:

Output the elements of the array in 10 columns that are 6 spaces wide.  Each row in the output will have 10 values.  It is a double array, and the doubles will be printed out to only 2 decimal places. Heres my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    double array[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        array[i] = (double)(rand() % 100 + 1) / 2.0;

        printf("%.2lf      \n", array[i]);

        if ( i == 9 || i == 19 || i == 29 || i == 39 || i == 49 || i == 59 || i == 69 || i == 79 || i == 89 || i == 99) {
            printf("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

All this seems to do is print one column with space in between every 10, not what I need.  How would I go about doing a multiple column output in this situation? Thanks

Comment: `printf("%.2lf \n", array[i]);`... What is that newline at the end of the format string doing?

Comment: On another note, that long condition could simply be `if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `\n` from the `printf`

`printf("%.2lf      ", array[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

> Output the elements of the array in 10 columns that are 6 spaces wide.

The format specifier used in the posted code doesn't do that

```
printf("%.2lf      \n", array[i]);
//       ^^   ^^^^ ^^
```

- The `\n` at the end forces the ouptut of only *one* value per line.
- The precision specifier is correct, but instead of using a width specifier before the point it uses some space characters *after* the value. This won't enforce the correct width of each column.

There are other possible issues in this program.

- It uses `rand` without seeding its pseudo-random generator with `srand`. It's unclear if the OP wants the same sequence every time for testing porpuses or if more entropy is needed.
- As noted in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64144784/outputting-an-array-in-column-format#comment113429924_64144784), the condition in the `if` statement could be simplified.

The following is a possible fix of those issues.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 100
#define N_COLUMNS 10

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    double array[ARR_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (double)(rand() % 100 + 1) / 2.0;

        printf("%6.2lf", array[i]);
        //      ^^^^^^
        
        if ( (i + 1) % N_COLUMNS == 0 ) {
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
}
```